# Cannot access private constructors of a Friend class

Tags: c++, friend

I have the following two classes:

```
struct Entity 
{
    unsigned id;
    Entity(unsigned id);
    Entity();
};

class EntityManager
{
public:
    Entity create();
    ...

private:
    Entity make_entity(unsigned index, unsigned generation);
};
```

This works fine at the moment. The problem is the encapsulation. I dont want to allow the direct creating of the class `Entity`.

Because of that, my goal is to make the constructors of `Entity`private. Then I could (from what I understand) mantain functionality in `EntityManager` by making `Entity` a `friend` of `EntityManager`.

So making the changes this would be the result:

```
struct Entity 
{
    unsigned id;
private:
    Entity(unsigned id);
    Entity();
};

class EntityManager
{
    friend struct Entity;
public:
    Entity create();

private:
    Entity make_entity(unsigned index, unsigned generation);
};
```

That breaks the code. The error that I get is this one:

```
entity_manager.cpp: In member function ‘Entity EntityManager::make_entity(unsigned int, unsigned int)’:
entity_manager.cpp:12:1: error: ‘Entity::Entity(unsigned int)’ is private
 Entity::Entity(unsigned id) : id(id) {}
 ^
entity_manager.cpp:19:21: error: within this context
     return Entity(id);
                     ^
```

The implementation file is like this one:

```
Entity::Entity() : id(0) {}
Entity::Entity(unsigned id) : id(id) {}

Entity EntityManager::make_entity(unsigned idx, unsigned  generation)
{
    unsigned id = 0;
    id = ...
    return Entity(id);
}

Entity EntityManager::create()
{
    ...
    return make_entity(..., ...);
}
```

Is there anything obvious that I am missing here? I also tried calling `Entity(id)` on the implementation as `Entity::Entity(id)`, but I then get another error:

```
entity_manager.cpp: In member function ‘Entity EntityManager::make_entity(unsigned int, unsigned int)’:
entity_manager.cpp:19:29: error: cannot call constructor ‘Entity::Entity’ directly [-fpermissive]
     return Entity::Entity(id);

                             ^
entity_manager.cpp:19:29: note: for a function-style cast, remove the redundant ‘::Entity’
entity_manager.cpp:12:1: error: ‘Entity::Entity(unsigned int)’ is private
 Entity::Entity(unsigned id) : id(id) {}
 ^
entity_manager.cpp:19:29: error: within this context
     return Entity::Entity(id);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the `friend` declaration backwards.  You need to have this line in the `Entity` struct:

```
friend class EntityManager;
```

Answer (score 2):

The friend declaration needs to go in the `Entity` class, not the `EntityManager` class.  Otherwise, any arbitrary class could access another class's private data just by placing `friend class X` in their declaration.  The class that wishes to share its private data has to explicitly declare so.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
struct Entity;

class EntityManager
{
public:
    Entity create();

private:
    Entity make_entity(unsigned index, unsigned generation);
};

struct Entity 
{
private:
    unsigned id;
    Entity(unsigned id);
    Entity();
    friend Entity EntityManager::make_entity(unsigned index, unsigned generation);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your `friend` declaration backward.  The friending class contains private (and/or protected) members that can be used by the friended class.

```
struct Entity 
{
    unsigned id;
private:
    Entity(unsigned id);
    Entity();
    friend class EntityManager;
};
```